# how can i dismiss the progress bar dialog after image is loaded into the imageview from firebase storage with glide

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

After loading image into imageview progress bar also visible it's not dismiss

```
   StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://project-b2310.appspot.com/computer/cm_fifth/cg_winter_15.1.jpg");
        StorageReference gsReference1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://project-b2310.appspot.com/computer/cm_fifth/cg_winter_15.2.jpg");
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading");
        pd.show();
        Glide.with(paper_loader.this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(gsReference).into(img);
        Glide.with(paper_loader.this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(gsReference1).into(img1);
        if (img.getDrawable() != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        if (img1.getDrawable() != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
```

[image: here is the output]

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by a little bit code:

```html
pd.show();
Glide.with(getActivity())
     .load(args.getString(IMAGE_TO_SHOW))
     .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             pd.dismiss();
             return false;
         }
     })
     .into(imageFrame)
;
```

Will work like a charm, Cheers...

ps: Sorry for posting in snippet

Comment: You can use dismiss() and show() methods instead of `setVisibilty(GONE)` or   `setVisibilty(VISIBLE)`, because this answer is just to show you the *listenener* that listen to load finishing... | The reason why given methods don't show is that these methods can be only set to Views, but for Progressdialog the equivalent of these methods are different.